# Grunt can not find task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, ecmascript-6, traceur

Something went wrong with my grunt config and I can not figure out what. Giver part of my grunfile.js

```
grunt.initConfig({
    traceur: {
        options: {
            blockBinding: true
        },
        custom: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'public/js',
                src: ['*.js'],
                dest: 'public/components'
            }]
        }
    },
    watch: {
        js: {
            files: ['public/js/*.js'],
            tasks: [' traceur' ]
        }
    }
    /* ... */
});
```

I register two tasks from above:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
grunt.registerTask('tr', ['traceur']);
```

While running `grunt tr` everything is fine. But when `watch` task tries to run `traceur` after code changed I'll get error:

```
>> File "public/js/app.js" changed. 
Fatal error: Task " traceur" not found
```

Why does not grunt find traceur task?

Comment: There seems to be a space in your error: `Fatal error: Task " traceur" not found`. Are you sure that they is not an additional space in your code ?

Comment: Remove leading white space from config. Should be: `tasks: ['traceur']`.

Comment: I don't even know what to say. You know I have tried to solve this problem for half an hour ). Thank you, guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a leading white space in front of the task in the `watch` section.

```
watch: {
    js: {
        files: ['public/js/*.js'],
        tasks: [' traceur' ]
    }
}
```

Change to:

```
watch: {
    js: {
        files: ['public/js/*.js'],
        tasks: ['traceur']
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes because of stackoverflow restrictions ) Thank you